# Laravel PHP Data To AngularJS Script File - No Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am trying to do something that I thought would be a simple task, but can't seem to get a good answer on.

I have a Laravel application that needs to send data to the client running AngularJS.

For example, the Laravel code:

```
public function home()
{
$data = $this->user->getUserParams();
return view('content.auth.home')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Easy enough. And then if I wanted to `ng-repeat` the `data` I would use a PHP `echo` or the blade templating to put the data from my php function in AngularJS's scope and iterate over it.

My problem is I don't want my Angular scripts being served between `<script>` tags in the blade template. I need them to be served from external `.js` files.

So what is the best practice to pass the PHP data to an external `.js` script? I don't want to load the page then `$http` for the data because that would be a lot slower than simply having it on page render. I also don't want to have a global variable in between `<script>` tags that the external AngualarJS is supposed to pick up. Is there no way to manipulate Laravel's routing system to serve a `.js` file with PHP in it?

Comment: "I don't want to load the page then $http for the data because that would be a lot slower" Are you sure about that? I feel like that is a false premise. While it is possible to get PHP to generate and serve JS files, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It would be a little weird, but you could set the content type header in your controller action to serve up a blade file as javascript.

Comment: Best practice is to have your PHP and JS completely separate.

Comment: @jfadich Is it really best practice to load a page then run an ajax request for data you could have got the first time around (when you loaded the page)? If so I'll do it that way, I'm just surprised to find that's how it works.

Comment: Serving a static JS file will always be faster than serving a dynamic JS file generated by PHP. A static JS file can bypass PHP entirely and be cached. If you want to serve a JS file with the data preloaded you're doing to have to prevent caching and spend extra overhead generating the file. Instead serve a static APP JS file and load the data separately. The second best option you said you don't want (printing the data in a <script> tag)

Comment: @jfadich Thank you.